# Amazonaws blocked by modem?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, modem

since some time i have the following problem:
I can't download a .exe file (in my case the "Minecraft.exe" file) from s3.amazonaws.
It does not work on 2 laptops, which are connected with a Vodafone Modem "Vodafone Station 2" (i don't know if this is only the name Vodafone gave it or if it isthe correct name) over W-Lan.
If i go to the downloadpage over the link at "minecraft.net" the browser shows me "can't reach site", if i open the minecraft laauncher, which tryes to check for new versions on the amazonaws page, it throws me exceptions.
If i try the same thing on another modem (its a connection in another house) it works perfectly, which for me means, that the modem blocks it.
But if i go to the modems settings, there is no firewall enabled.
How can a modem block this connection, if no firewall is enabled?

I hope i was clear enught. If you need any other informations please tell me.

Thanks

**EDIT:** Some more informations: The same problem happend on (more then) 2 Notebooks:

1. The first is a new Notebook (5 days old) with Windows 8.1, 64 Bit
2. The second is a 5,5 years old Notebook with Win7 64 Bit

I disactivated the firewall as well as the antivirus for both. Maleware can't be the problem (it was for some others i found during my google search), as one Notebook is new. Also a bad java installation (again some others had this problem cause of bad java installation) can't be the problem.
It worked (with the new Notebook) on the other connection (other modem and other provider) so it has to be a problem of the modem or provider. But i really don't think it is a providers preoblem^^
So it can only be the modem (Vodafone Station 2).

Comment: Have you tried this with different browsers? Does this happen with files other than the Minecraft.exe launcher as well?

Comment: I have tryed it on different laptops, with different OS (win7 and win8), different browsers, firewall off, antivirus off. It happens with the file "Minecraft.exe" (link on minecraft.net) as well as with the version check made by the launcher (i think the version check checks another file on the s3.amazonaws page). it does not happen on the other connection, with another modem (the other modem is a alice modem).

Comment: @private_meta do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Apart from "Your ISP is blocking this", I have no answer for you. I was just asking the obvious questions that were not already answered in your Question. Also could be amazonaws blocking your ISP or IP

Comment: @private_meta thanks anyways :) I don't really think it is the ISP, i think there should be a hidden setting in the modem configs i just don't see. bad question: Could it be something in the port-forwarding settings? I really don't think so but as much as i see its the last setting that could cause this problem...

Comment: I don't know your current setup all too well. From what I find about "Vodafone Station 2" it's an italian ADSL modem.

Usually outgoing connections do not need any kind of port-forwarding. Port forwarding is done if a device on the inside works as a server and someone on the outside needs to connect. As the devices you use work on another modem, the computers setup seems to be correct, leaving router, ISP or server (amazonaws). If it's the router, those usually DO NOT block anything by default. So, if you look through your router/modem config and do not find anything there that's being blocked

Comment: It can only be the ISP or the Server, amazonaws. A simple call or mail to your ISP tech support should not hurt you too much, and it could very well solve your issue.

Comment: It's Vodafone blocking s3.amazonaws.com for no apparent reason. Source: unfortunately I have that at work and I'm forced to use a VPN to access my stuff on s3

Comment: @Magnetic_dud Hi and thanks for your reply. I solved this problem by using Googles Public DNS, instead of the default one. Now i can download  the Minecraft.exe without problems, so it seems that this was the problem.

Comment: @Springrbua no, Vodafone hijacks any DNS requests to use their DNS servers (at least with my Vodafone Station 2)

Comment: @Magnetic_dud well, for me it seemed to work. As soon as i changed the DNS-Server, the launcher was able to do the version check + download the latest version. But it might depend on the country (i live in italy) or maybe on the modem/router.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the DNS-Configuration.
I am now using Google-DNS and it seems to work for me.
I can now download the ".exe" and also the versioncheck in the launcher works.

Hope this can help someone else to.